# Find whether $a_n = \frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$a_n = \frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}$

Because this is an alternating series first I tried to find whether $|a_n|$ converges.

$$|a_n|= \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2}$$

I tried to compare this with $1/n^2$:

$$\lim \frac{\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \lim |\sin(n)|$$

I'm unsure about what to do next? This limit goes anywhere between $0$ and $1$. Since $1/n^2$ converges, so does this series. Because when the limit is $]0;1]$ they both converge, and when it's 0 since $1/n^2$ converges, so does $a_n$. Is this correct? If so, then Leibniz's criteria isn't applied here and the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Are you considering $n \to 0$ or $n \to \infty$?  When you say *series* are you considering the sum?

Comment: Worth noting:  the series (or sequence) is not alternating.  Yes, there are both positive and negative terms, but the pattern of signs is tricky.  Leibniz does not apply.

Comment: @Henry The limit goes to infinity and no I am not considering the sum... I think. All the exercise asks is to find whether it converges or not.

Comment: The word *series* has a definite meaning. Are you considering the sequence of terms $\sin n/n^2$? If so this goes to $0$ at $n=+\infty$ since the numerator is bounded by a constant and the denominator becomes arbitrarily large.

Comment: You have presented a sequence, but mention an alternating series. Are you looking at $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}$ or $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}$?

Comment: @robjohn The latter, I thought it was implied. Sorry

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire why have you accepted my answer then? I only showed convergence of the sequence $a_n$. I can try showing convergence of series as well. Do you want that?

Comment: @ironX Sure. Apologies. I think I misread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can easily show that this sequence converges absolutely which implies convergence of sequence.

To show absolute convergence of sequence, \begin{align*}
|a_n|  &= \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n^2} \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align*}

To show convergence of series, we first show convergence of $\sum |a_n|$.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2}\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{6} 
\end{align*}
This implies for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^N |a_n| \leq \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Since the partial sums $\sum \limits_{n=1}^N |a_n|$ are upper bounded, **Theorem 1** implies $\sum |a_n|$ indeed converges.

**Theorem 1** A series of nonnegative terms converges if and only if its partial sums form a bounded sequence.

Convergence of $\sum |a_n|$ implies convergence of $\sum a_n$