# Confused about the comparison test for series, finding whether $\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have asked [something similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545869/finding-whether-sum-frac-lnnn-diverges-or-converges-using-a-comparison) before but I still have some questions.

I'm trying to find if $\ln(n)/n^3$ converges or not by comparing it with $1/n^3$. I'm trying to solve it similarly to the way my professor solved it in the post I linked but now I am a bit confused about the comparison test. I thought the way it went was that I have to find a $b_n$ that was $\ge a_n$. I try to solve this:

$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3} \le \frac{1}{n^3} \Leftrightarrow \\
\ln(n) \le 1 \Leftrightarrow \\
n \le e$$

Then what I normally do I to solve for $a_n/b_n$:
$$\lim \frac{\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}}{\frac{1}{n^3}} = \lim \ln(n) $$

which doesn't exist. I'm confused.

1) Am I using the comparison test wrong? Are both of these steps just two of the same thing?

2) I don't get it why (in the link for one) the function diverges even if the condition only checks out for a certain range. Does it converge in this case if the condition is only true for $n \le e$? I'm confused.

Comment: You shouldn't use $\frac1{n^3}$ as the comparison, rather $\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: @DonThousand why?

Comment: Note that $$0<\frac{\ln n}{n^3}\leq\frac n{n^3}=\frac1{n^2}$$And $\frac1{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: @DonThousand  $\lim \frac{\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = 0$, so it does converge... what about the example in the link? should I have used $1/\sqrt{n}$ for the comparison?

Comment: Please clarify whether you are speaking about the sequence or the series.  Between this and your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556081/find-whether-a-n-frac-sinnn2-converges), you seem very confused about the difference.

Comment: @lulu I'm talking about the series $\sum \ln(n)/n^3$

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect that.  Similarly in your prior question, where you can see from the comments that people had a lot of trouble guessing what you meant.

Comment: @lulu Either way, what I commented works.

Comment: @DonThousand It still doesn't answer the question which was how to apply the comparison test

Comment: I applied the test lol.

Answer (score 2):

What you found says that only the first 2 elements of your series ($n \le e$ means $n=1$ or $n=2$) are in fact smaller than the respective elements of the series you want to compare it to, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^3}$.

That means the comparison test, used with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^3}$ as your majorant, doesn't help you to decide if your series converges or not. It doesn't prove it, it doesn't disprove it. You simply used an unsuitable series to compare your series with.

The comments should give you enough hints what a suitable series to compare your series with could be. If you want to know "How do I find such a suitable comparison series on my own?", then the answer is as usual: Try to read the solutions to similar problems, and see if you can find a pattern that "usually seems to work".